# Azure Create VM With New Storage Account

Tags: command-line-interface, azure, deployment

I'm currently trying to automate the deployment of virtual clusters. Every one of the machines / cluster should get its own storage account to keep things faster and also make deletion easier.

Scripting with Azure CLI is so far without problems, only when trying to use another storage account then where our own image is located, I get the error that the image and target VHD for the new machine must be located in the same storage account.

`The disk's VHD must be in the same account as the VHD of the source image (source account: foo, target account: bar`

Am I right in assuming this is an API limitation? Anyone has a recommendation how to work around this?

Obvious way around is kind of a pain in the ass because I have to copy the image blob from one account to another before deploying the virtual machine, which is not really an option for time reasons.

Comment: Do you Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI? Do you use a Platform Image or own Image? Please provide the exact set of configuration/commands you use (stripping/hiding sensitive information)!

Comment: I updated the question, we use the azure CLI and its our own image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a design limitation. You can work around it as you suggested by doing a CopyBlob from your source image to the target container/storage account. If the accounts are in the same cluster, the copy should be almost instantaneous and you should not see an issue with copy times.